# CSS background starting below variable header

Tags: html, css, background-image

**Question**

I'd like the CSS background texture for my content area to begin immediately after a variable-height header. The texture has a natural height of 900px and is graduated to a flat color, so if it fits in the available space between content-start and body-end, the whole texture should be displayed. The texture shouldn't artificially expand the content area or cause unnecessary scroll, but scroll should still appear when content is longer than fits in the page.

**JSFiddle**

On request, here's a JSFiddle of my issue. Since there's really only one DOM element in the question, I think the fiddle doesn't clarify much. http://jsfiddle.net/AbEUe/5/

**What doesn't work**

```
#contentAndBackground {
    padding-bottom: 900px;
    margin-bottom: -900px;
    background: url('my900pxHighImage.png') repeat-x;
}
```

The above ensures the whole image is shown, but the negative margin doesn't keep the unnecessary scrollbars away as I'd hoped.

```
#contentAndBackground {
    min-height: 900px;
    background: url('my900pxHighImage.png') repeat-x;
}
```

Same problem. The whole image is shown, but scrollbars are always showing.

I'd like to avoid using JavaScript that needs to handle screen resizing.

Comment: Any chance of a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo?

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to. It may not elucidate much, since the whole issue is really about one div with a background, and jsfiddle doesn't do backgrounds. some way for me to store a background?

Comment: http://dummyimage.com/ or http://placekitten.com/. There are a lot of choices :)

Comment: here you can store the background images :- http://imgur.com/

Comment: Awesome, will have it posted in 10 minutes, including the various scenarios.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're looking for `min-height:900px`. Am I correct?

Comment: Shouldn't you just put the background in a div below the header, instead of using it as background of the header parent div. Assuming the header has 100% width, this should leave no empty spaces.

Comment: @tangelo: Yes, except that will cause the scrollbar to display, without content in the scrolled area. Similarly, body { min-height: 100%; background-image: url('myimage.png'); } would work if the background shouldn't start after the variable header.

Comment: @Gerard: That's exactly what I want to do. Except if the content is short, then the background terminates abruptly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I did it: http://jsfiddle.net/AbEUe/7/

I have created 2 container divs, both have a height of 100%.

- The first contains header and background, and has `overflow:hidden` so the background is stopped at the bottom.
- The second contains header and content, and because of use of positioning this one is on top of the first container, and it can stretch to more than 100% (if the amount of text requires that).

You can see you have to render the header twice, but that won't matter because the first isnt visible.

**Edit:**

Solved the last problem (see comment) by also setting the background to the content div. See http://jsfiddle.net/AbEUe/8/

Comment: Oh wait, there is problem: the background outside scrollable view isnt visible :p But this may be the direction for the solution.

Comment: Ok, it took me a moment to understand it. It still may be the best way, but because the header has active content in it, I hate to generate it twice. It could lead to defects, if say, it depended on the time and it changed between the two renders, or if the header had internal side-effects, or if it had DOM IDs in it, etc.

Comment: I'll reflag your answer in a bit, but I'll leave it open and award additional points to an improved answer.

Comment: Discussed it with the designer, who agreed to work toward another layout. I'll still award that bonus to whomever comes up with another solution.

Comment: You didnt talk about active content in your question. But in that case I would use javascript (you're already using it) to get the height of the header and apply it to the dummy header in container1.

Comment: well, there are lots of things I didn't talk about that the site does. active content in the header is pretty common. I'm certainly not complaining about your help. re: javascript, it's an entirely different issue to run javascript based on standard and supported events, than to run javascript that has to monitor screen size changes, adjust local CSS elements (overriding any potential class logic developers of sub-pages may want to use), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but this prevents your kitties from being chopped up.

```
#content {background: url('http://placekitten.com/g/200/300') repeat-x; min-height:300px;}
```

Comment: Thank you Jezen. The actual image provided by design is 900px high. The designer's intent was to cover the screen for most of our community, so applying a min-height of that will trigger false scroll for everyone, which I'm trying to avoid.